# Does MySQL Partitioning Require Special Queries To Take Advantage After Creating It?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-partitioning, table-partitioning

I'm a newbie when it comes to MySQL/MariaDB partitions, and haven't created one yet, but am reading up on it. My first question is, if I partition a table by year and then month based on a dt_created DATETIME column, do I need to change the way I'm doing SQL queries in order to start to see a performance increase when I'm doing a single day query on dt_created? Or, does a standard query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM web_tracking_events where dt_created >= '(some time goes here)'
```

work good enough?

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint, if you haven't already

Comment: Partitioning does not inherently produce any performance benefit.  (There are a small number of exceptions; your use case is not one of them.)  As for the Title question -- no syntax changes in the queries.

Comment: @RickJames I understand that you're an accepted pro at this. So, you talked me out of partitioning. Thanks for your rich information about this on the web! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically. you can do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM web_tracking_events where dt_created >= '(some time goes here)'
```

This is called pruning. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html

However, that means that mysql will open **all partitions** to check if it finds a match there.